# Redirection in .htaccess with variable parameters and pass through

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I've having trouble working out the correct entries to put into my .htaccess file.

What I'm trying to do is:

**1) Allow all requests for certain file types to work correctly. (ie jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)**

This will allow all files included with web pages to work correctly.

**2) All requests to "login" to be redirected to login page, with parameters. eg**

```
/login
/Login        (different case)
/login/
/login/index.py
/login/scipt/index.py
/login?id=1&attr=foobar
/login/index.py?mode=1&attr=foobar?name=Billy
/login/scipt/index.py?index=999
/login/?anotherparam=value      (basically, the parameter list can vary)
```

Should ALL redirect to:

```
/login.py
```

And those with GET parameters, should redirect to:

```
/login.py?(copied list of parameters without these brackets)
```

**3) Everything else should be redirected to root (ie '/') keeping any parameters. eg**

```
/NotAPage.html
/NotAFolder/
/NotAFolder/NotAPage.html
/NotAPage.html?v=1&k=2
/NotAFolder/?a=2
/NotAFolder/NotAPage.html?a=99&b=55&c=99   (again, the parameter list can vary)
```

Should ALL redirect to:

```
/
```

And those with GET parameters, should redirect to:

```
/?(copied list of parameters without these brackets)
```

---

So far, I've gotten this far:

```
#Make PY (Python) files executable outside of CGI-BIN
AddHandler cgi-script .py
Options +ExecCGI

# Turn on URL rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

# Allow these file types to pass through untouched
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$
# Redirect all other requests to index.py
RewriteRule (.*) index.py [L,PT]
```

Which, I believe, is getting everything (except the list of suffixes) to redirect to index.py, with parameters, but it's not doing everything I need yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
Options +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^login [NC]
RewriteRule . index.py [QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^login [NC]
RewriteRule . login.py [QSA,PT]
```

The `PT` flag implies the `L` flag: rewriting will be stopped in order to pass the request to the next phase of processing.

Note that the `PT` flag is implied in per-directory contexts such as `<Directory>` sections or in `.htaccess` files. The only way to circumvent that is to rewrite to `-`.